# Allow only certain non alpha characters in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am try to write a regular expression in javascript that will not allow non-alpha characters with the exception of  only one occurrence of the following `.,!-`

This was what I was trying but it does not seem to work.

```
/^[ 0-9a-zA-Zs][,.!]{1,}+$/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some examples for further clarification. If a user types the following:

- This is a test! (pass)
- This is test!! (fail)
- This is a - test (pass)
- This is a test.(pass)
- This is a, test (pass)
- This is a,,test(fail)
- This is a test? (pass)
- This is a test?? (fail)
- $7,500 (fail)
- 7,500 (pass)

Comment: Try http://refiddle.com to build your expression, you can write a list of values that should match and then it will highlight when it should match and when it shouldn't. Helps in tweaking complex regexes.

Comment: Example at http://refiddle.com/10j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[\w ]+([.,!-?][\w ]*)?$/
```

---

```
#+ Valid values
allow.periods
allow!bangs
allow-dashes
allow,commas
alphaonly
3numeric
This is a test!
This is a - test
This is a test.
This is a, test
This is a test?
7,500

#- Invalid values
no^
---
!
!!
two..periods
This is test!!
This is a,,test
This is a test??
$7,500
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*[,.!]?[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Only problem is that it will match , by itself.  You'd need to decide if you are going to allow  a,    ,a  and  ,

All of those match your original criteria literally, but probably aren't what you meant.

Here is the same with expanded first and last sections as suggested by zobgib below.

```
/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[,.!]?[0-9a-zA-Z]*)|([0-9a-zA-Z]*[,.!]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$/
```

Comment: See my edit.  If you want at least one alpha-numeric in the string, then you are correct, you need first and last or's.  If not, then the current solution works.  Also, the original author might want the string to start with an alpha numeric.  In that case changing the first * to a plus will give the desired behavior.

Comment: The `^(..)|(..)$` is wrong. It needs to be either `^(..)$|^(..)$` or `^((..)|(..))$`.

Answer (score 0):

`/^[^.,!-]+[.,!-]?[^.,!-]+?$/`

Breaking it down anything that isn't `.,!-` followed by maybe one of `.,!-` followed by maybe anything that isn't `.,!-`

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.,!-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+?$/`

This will match any alpha character with one occurrence of the following

Comment: This will match a lot of things.  For example ### or +++.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I was unable to get what you posted to work. Let me try to explain. 


SO the idea is that they can have only one of the following in a alpha string. 
!,?&.-_

Any other non alpha characters in a sting would fail. It does not matter where in the string they appear if there is more then one of these characters !,?&.-_ or any other non-alpha characters in the sting it should fail.

Comment: Here are some examples for further calrification 

If a user types the following 
This is a test! (Pass)
This is test!! (Fail)
This is a - test (pass)
This is a test.(pass)
This is a, test (pass)
This is a,,test(fail)
This is a test? (pass)
This is a test?? (fail)
$7,500 (fail)
7,500 (pass)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+[,.!]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/
```

must contain one character before and one after the possible non alpha character.

should match a,a but not a, or ,a....

alternatively you can change the + for * to allow 0 or more occurances.

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+[,.!]?[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

this would match HELLO! but not !helooo

you can also get a cheat sheet here http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

using this cheat sheet you may even be able to get away with

```
/^[:alnum:]+[,.!]?[:alnum:]*$/
```

but that may be language specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([,.!-]|[0-9a-zA-Z]+[,.!-])[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

This will match one of your exceptions OR 
any number of alphanums followed by one exception,
and either match followed by zero or more alphanums.